# Is there need MVC installed for IIS 7 for non MVC project too?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, web-deployment

In ASP.NET empty web application created on 4.5.2 framework, deploying in IIS 7 windows 10.

application does not have dependency on MVC though, it gives an error when deployed on IIS and execute.

error: could not load MVC 5.2.3.0 assembly.

Is it min requirement for IIS 7 to need MVC ? or any solution .

when i add MVC files to project then it works. but i don't want to add as there is not dependency. all JS and html files are only.

Comment: do you have any DLL related to ASP.NET MVC referenced in your project?

Comment: nope. even plain ASP.NET EMPTY project with one html still give same issue.